# Solution for Multidomain Email?

Tags: email, debian, postfix-mta, dovecot

I'm using a custom root server to handle multiple domains on one IP. The basic OS is Debian and the WWW is done with: Nginx+MariaDB.

Now I'm trying to install any working non MySQL based Email service on it. I've watched several tutorials and googled the whole web for a solution.
My last attempt was to work with Postfix and Dovecot. The emails was kind of identified but getting the error:

```
<domain.org/info@mail.domain.com> (expanded from <info@domain.org>):
    mail for mail.domain.com loops back to myself
```

1. Is there a step by step explanation for multidomain mail alias setting that is not running on any MySQL?
2. Do I need to run my virtual emails on MySQL?
3. Any Cpanel or Plesk like interface that could handle virtual Email aliases on non MySQL basis?

Answer (score 0):

1. postfix can use mysql as a backend, but it's not required. Usually you can find tutorials on the net just using the db files.
2. no, you don't have to.
3. No idea. I usually do that stuff directly in the files or with a database backend.

This question might be better suited for serverfault, but it's pretty generic as it stands.